# Render zoomed further than viewport

Tags: rendering

So I'm trying to render a scene, and everything looks fine in the viewport. But when I go to render it, it seems to have zoomed in way further than it's supposed to. I think it's zooming in on the backpack, but I have no idea why it would do that. There's nothing inside the camera, and there's nothing set to render that's not visible in the viewport. The first image is what it should look like, and the second image is what I get when I render it. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your scene to only include the most necessary parts to produce the error and upload it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. This way other will be able to help your more easily.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3226" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3226/)

not sure what you meant about editing it, but here's the file (i think?)

Comment: It is due to the particle system set on the ground (coniferous)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why that broke it since it wasn't actually in use, but I'm just glad it's working now.